# SET is not valid at this position. Expecting an identifier

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE holdings A
SET A.username = 
(select username from transaction_history
group by username, symbol),
SET A.symbol = (select symbol from transaction_history
group by username, symbol);

update holdings A
set A.username = 12, A.symbol = 24;
```

Here, for example, I have taken the second query where it works fine but there is an error in the first query "SET is not valid at this position. Expecting an identifier."

Comment: There's no `WHERE` in the update syntax so I assume that you want to update everything with a single value, is it? Also, what a strange thing to do a `SELECT` of one column but grouping it with 2 columns. I suppose each subquery should be something like `SELECT username .... GROUP BY username` and `SELECT symbol .... GROUP BY symbol` instead, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have two `SET` in your first sql, need to remove the last one

```
UPDATE holdings A
SET A.username = 
(select username from transaction_history
group by username, symbol),
A.symbol = (select symbol from transaction_history
group by username, symbol);
```

also, you need to make sure the sub query only return one rows, so I would advice add `limit` inside it

```
UPDATE holdings A
SET A.username = 
(select username from transaction_history
group by username, symbol limit 1),
A.symbol = (select symbol from transaction_history
group by username, symbol limit 1);
```

Comment: That did not update holdings table. The code did run but 0 rows affected. (It has symbol and username as it's attributes)

Comment: @RayoneGautam can you add some sample data in your original question? also you need to consider if`group by username, symbol` meets your demand

Comment: sample data of transaction_history?

Comment: @RewanGautam yes